pytest: Unable to mock certain module under package while all other modules can be mocked
I have a fixture mocking all the get_session invocations under a specific package. This is how the fixture mocks all these invocation
@pytest.fixture(name="mock_flask_db_session", scope="function")
def mock_flask_db_session(
        mocker: pytest_mock.MockerFixture, test_app_context: AppContext
) -> Generator[pytest_mock.MockFixture, None, None]:
    packages_to_mock = [
        p.name
        for p in pkgutil.iter_modules(flask_utils.__path__)
    ]
    mocked_get_sessions = [
        mocker.patch(f"flask.utils.{package}.get_session", autospec=True)
        for package in packages_to_mock
    ]

    # Create a mock session object
    mock_session = MagicMock(spec=sa.orm.scoped_session)
    for mgs in mocked_get_sessions:
        mgs.return_value = mock_session

    with test_app_context:
        yield mock_session

    # Reset the mock after the test
    mock_session.reset_mock(return_value=True, side_effect=True)

I am usually writing tests like
def test_bla_utils(test_app_context, mock_flask_db_session):
    some_utils_package.get_eval_result(1, 1)

Inside the get_eval_result there's a get_session invocation which is perfectly mocked.
I am able to mock all get_session in all the modules under flask.utils package but one. On this one there's a decorator defined
def dododo(
        a: bool = False,
        b: bool = False,
        c: UserPrivileges = None,
):


    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            db = get_session()
            # to stuff
        return wrapper

    return decorator

The decorator wraps Flask endpoints and provides custom user management. That is why it needs access to the databse.
In this case - and only in this case - get_session always returning None. What am I doing wrong here?
//EDIT
I've spent the entire day today on this one. I ended up building a new application using only the relevant components:

The create_app method
The api Blueprint
The auth_decorators
The conftest
The actual tests

it works perfectly. I can mock the session and if I wrap the get_session into another method
def foo():
   return get_session()

I can easily mock the foo method. The only thing I can think of going wrong here is the precedence of imports but I don't know where to start checking this.
I've spent more than 10 hours now on this one.
